# Using null values with try..catch statement in typescript

Tags: typescript, null, try-catch

I am trying to write a try/catch statement in typescript
there is a function in "try" that returns null.
how to apply code in "catch" when the returned value from the function in "try" is null?
see below:

```
try {
const availableimg= await imgpath({filename,width,height});
  res.send(`${availableimg}`)
} catch {
//I want this code here to be applied if the imgpath function returned null!
}
```

Sorry if there are mistakes I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Just `throw` if null !

```
try {
const availableimg= await imgpath({filename,width,height});
  res.send(`${availableimg}`)
  if(availableimg === null) {
      throw new Error('Null image')
  }
} catch {
   // will be catch if availableimg  == null
}
```